# Excel 365 Slow Scrolling due to Notes and Comments

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, office365, scrolling, microsoft-excel-365

An Excel spreadsheet containing any 'notes' (previously known as 'comments' in some earlier Excel versions) is slow to scroll up and down when holding down  the up/down arrow keys. For example, even on a new workbook created as a blank workbook, after one 'note' is added (right-click, new note) in cell A1 the scrolling action becomes 'jumpy' - jumps 4 or five rows at a time. If the note is deleted then the sheet scrolls normally. Previously I had used Excel 2010 which did not have this problem. This has been tested on two machines. Win 10. Excel version 1903. Can anyone else reproduce this behaviour? Any solutions?

The same problem is apparent when adding comments (i.e. threaded comments, as distinct from "notes") but only where the comment has been 'posted'.

This has now been tested on three machines and the problem is there even when running Excel in Safe Mode. This problem (or something rather similar) seems to have also been experienced at [here](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/7348).

Comment: I received notification by email of an answer which apparently began: "I've had this exact problem for years now on excel 2016, even the older version without the threa..." This answer is not accessible in my inbox. If someone has deleted it please reinstate it as it appears to confirm that someone else has the same problem, which answers the first of my two questions.

Comment: This is now also listed on ExpertsExchange.

Comment: Any answer that indicates they also have the problem, is not actually an answer and is subject to be removed by the community, questions seeking that type of response is subject to be closed to prevent those type of answers.  Only answers that explain how to prevent or solve your problem will be kept.  Super User is not a forum, an answer that indicate somebody also has a problem, are not considered to be content worthy of being kept.

Comment: It's useful for me to know whether other users have the same problem as a 'sanity check' to ensure that I had not misinterpreted the problem's symptoms. It's useful to know other users' operating system environments to help establish whether this is an application problem or not. It's useful to know other sufferers' application versions to establish whether the problem is unique to  Excel 365. Whilst such info is not a solution it may provide insight which might lead to one. That said, I don't make Super User rules but will of course comply with them in future as expressed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have the same problem using Microsoft Surface book. However, if I open the same spreadsheet in Excel 2010 - not a problem If I open on an old Dell machine (running windows 10 and basic Intel graphics adapter) works fine.

My hack is to:
1) Check the "Disable Hardware Acceleration" option in Excel
2) Change the display resolution so instead of the 3000x2000 default, change to 1200x or 1300x. This fixes the scrolling but the screen resolution is bit blurry unfortunately.

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration in Excel helps a lot, although does not fully solve the problem. Oddly, it makes more of an improvement under Win 10 1903 compared to 1809. Speculation, but this might be related to the Nvidia GPU problems which Surface Book has under 1903 (and according to https://www.askwoody.com/askwoody-newsletter-alerts/why-cant-microsoft-reliably-patch-its-own-hardware/ had previously). Difficult to know if this is the case without knowing whether non-Surface Book users have the same problem.